# C++: Returning a member variable by reference in member function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
class HeavyClass {

    public:
        static inline HeavyClass const &get() { // note the &
            return h_;
        }
    private:
        static HeavyClass h_;
};

HeavyClass HeavyClass::h_();

int main() {
    HeavyClass foo = HeavyClass::get(); // critical line
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, will this actually do what I want at the critical line? That is, will foo be a copy of h_, or actually h_ as if it's passed by reference?

Many thanks!

Comment: "will this actually do what I want", you forgot to tell us what you want.

Comment: You can easily test it by defining a constructor that prints some assertions.

Comment: The next sentence "will A or not A happen?", which one do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a copy.

The function `get` does indeed return a reference, but you are assigning it by-value:

```
HeavyClass foo = HeavyClass::get(); // critical line
```

On the critical line here, the critical *part* is the definition of `foo`.  `foo` isn't a reference-to-`HeavyClass` -- it's a `HeavyClass` itself.  Therefore, `foo` *cannot be* a reference to anything.

There is no magic in C++, only logic.  Well, OK, maybe there is magic, but none of it is hidden.  It;'s all in plain sight.  Here you declared a `HeavyClass`, not a reference-to-`HeavyClass`, so it doesn't magically become a reference.

If you want a reference, declare foo like this:

```
const HeavyClass& foo = HeavyClass::get()
```

By the way, it looks like you're trying to build a Singleton.  Please, at least research and be cognizant of all the arguments why Singletons are considered to be generally bad before you continue.

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar before but forgot the const part. Now it does what I want, and I double-checked by printing the addresses. Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 3):

I would think you need something like:

```
const HeavyClass& foo = HeavyClass::get();
```

If you want `foo` to be `h_`.

Comment: This gives "invalid initialization of reference of type 'HeavyClass&' from expression of type 'const HeavyClass'"

Comment: To be more clear, a copy is being avoided up to the point where `get()` returns; then a local variable `foo` is constructed by copying `h_`.

Comment: So it sounds like the correct way to do this is to actually return a pointer, is that right?

Comment: @bombax: No. It means that you're using code that is different from the one you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the right-hand side is not relevant for determining the type of the variable, which you have declared to be of type `HeavyClass`. So a new object of that type is instantiated and initialized with the value on the right. The fact the right-hand side is an lvalue doesn't matter (it will be subjected to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion).

Whether a function's return type is a reference or not doesn't change the *value* of the function call, only the value *category*.

Note that this is exactly the same with `auto`: If you had said `auto x = HeavyClass::get();`, it'd be the same, for the same reason (`auto` deduces type, not value category).